# Create an array of values between two numbers incremented a specific number of times?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've found the answer to this question before but I can't for the life of me find the source. The goal is to create an array of values between `9.5` and `10.9`, and in total the array needs to be incremented `513` times. The `9.5` and `10.9` are the first and last increment.

It's also important that every value is different, so decimal places should be moved back as far as necessary.

Hope I've explained the goal clear enough, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you exactly want but if you just count from 0 to 513 as in

```js
const start = 9.5;
const end = 10.9;
const times = 513;
const array = [];
for (let i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
  const u = i / (times - 1);            // this will go from 0 to 1
  const v = start + (end - start) * u;  // this will go from 9.5 to 10.9
  array.push(v);
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Nice. Can also be done on one line: `const splitInclusiveRange = (start, end, numItems) => Array.from({length: numItems}, (_, i) => start + i*(end - start)/(numItems - 1))`.

Comment: Using `Array.fill` like this is hacky and slow. It's filling the array twice, Once with `numItems` of `undefined` entries and then again with values. Testing in on jsperf it's literally > 10x slower than more traditional code like in the answer.